Embedded filters inside PCB?
I was looking at some videos where they showed up an X-ray picture of a multi-layer board with "embedded filters".
Thinking about PCB design practices, how You can embed or design a filter as such or components  which basically lay inside the PCB board??
i would like to understand the process and the methods.
I am adding the board for reference and for this example:



There is just not enough detail to answer your question. Your question is not deleted, it's on hold until you improve it based on feedback. But what kind of "filters" you are talking about? There are no filters that I could detect from the picture. And yes, capacitors, resistors and inductors can be embedded inside PCB, it is just not very often done, but mobile phone manufacturers 20 years ago did investigate on the issue.

yes they are filters.

i have added two picture representing the circuit and the x-ray of the same. i was just seeking general discussion on it and how these capacitors and resistors can be embedded inside a PCB board design...

The structure looks like a kind of transmission line made of 5 u shaped track inductors and 6 capacitors made of wide tracks. I assume it is a signal delay circuit or indeed a filter.

Looking at the x-ray and picture of the populated PCB I find it a bit confusing to manually correlate what is the same area in both pictures. The x-ray picture appears to be part of the "bottom right" area in the populated PCB and rotated anti-clockwise by 90 degrees. Is the board for a RF or microwave design?

@ChesterGillon is it is for microwave design. Actually is a Digital spectrum analyzer reaching 20 GHz . No the board are just superimposed (roughly) but not rotated.

correction. it was rotated. indeed the filters looks like they are represented by those differential lines then? . I have modified the picture.

While your question is still active, I suggest reviewing Microwave Filters and Resonators. David Pozar's Microwave Engineering, somewhere around Chapters 7, 8, 9 should be a good starting point.

@a360pilot thank you so much for this, I will!

Those do look like filters - but for radiofrequency, or RF.
All you see there are basically antennas of specific length, which means energy jumps from one antenna to another if the frequency matches the antenna length.
Also, every wire has inductance. And every metal wire, insulated from another metal wire, have capacitance between the wires.
So in RF design, you can use specifically designed wire structures acting as a filters, so you don't necessarily use discrete resistors, capacitors and inductors, as the RF energy flows outside the conductors as well.
The photo of the PCB looks exactly like innards of a device that processes RF signals in blocks and signals are passed between blocks.

Thanks! I was tricked because the x-ray image was rotated, so I thought caps and resistors were buried inside the PCB lol

but still I don't understand why they do this to "save space" in the board design. At the end, the area with these antennas is not occupied by other components so the space occupied is basically as to have them in the top or bottom layer....

@Ken90 Why do you think it's done to save spave? It might be larger now, but performs better and the impedances or transfer functions may be unrealizable with discrete resistors, capacitors and inductors due to their tolerances and parasitic properties.
